# py: command not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, window

Please help me resolve my problem.
I'm using vs code with git bash command for Python 3.12.0.
PROBLEM
bash: py: command not found

I have tried all possible way shown in YouTube and even google. Still nothing out there helps. Please help me
Thanks